# Data Source Name of Oracle SQL developer using SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to know the Data Source Name of Oracle SQL developer using SQL query? Can anyone help me?

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection 
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset cn.Open ( _ "User ID=hr" & _ ";Password=oracle_test" & _ ";Data Source=oscorp" & _ ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
```

Comment: Are you looking for `hostname` and `port`?

Comment: Or the database, instance or container name?

Comment: Data Source Name (DSN) usually refers to the name by which an ODBC connection is referred to.  I don't think that is what you want, so you should explain in more detail exactly what you are looking for and what you plan to do with it if/when you get it.  I suspect yet another x-y question here.

Comment: I need to know the DSN for Oracle sql developer.  See below code "Data Source" Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=hr" & _
    ";Password=oracle_test" & _
    ";Data Source=oscorp" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")

Comment: data source has nothing to do with sqldevloper.  check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: how to get dsn of oracle using sql query